# Symmetries of the high symmetry points in the Brillouin zone

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, crystals

The monolayer $MoS_2$ belongs to the $D_{3h}$ point group and can be described with a hexagonal lattice. The $\Gamma$-point in the Brillouin zone has the full symmetry of the point group, $D_{3h}$, but how do I identify the symmetries of the $K$ and $M$ points of the Brillouin zone?

[image]